# How to solve the problem of assigning products to assembly lines

Tags: algorithm, optimization, np-hard

I have been struggling with this problem from quite a while. Here's how it goes:

- There are N assembly lines having capacity C1, C2, ... CN.
- There are M products P1, P2, ... PM.
- Each product P is a set of Items {I1, I2, I3, ... Ik} which are finite.
- Products can share items.

We need to assign the products on the assembly lines such that following constraints are met:

1. Every product is assigned to exactly one of the lines.
2. Every line is able to accommodate all products assigned so that number of items on it never exceed it's capacity.

Some approaches I tried but didn't reach a satisfactory solution:

1. Started with pair of products with high Jaccard similarity assigned to each line and continued assigning more products on line.
2. Tried using LSH min hash to generate buckets of products with high similarity.

Both the approaches didn't generate a feasible solution. Meaning there were some products left at the end which would not fit on the assembly lines.

I'm only looking for a feasible solution (sub-optimal is fine) in this case and not the most optimised one.

Hoping someone give me more insights into solving this problem.

Comment: Is `Ci` the maximum number of *items* that can be processed by line i? You say that `P` is a product and then that it is a set. I think you need to re-word the reference to a set. I assume you mean that each product is comprised of a group of items (one each).

Comment: Yes `Ci` is the max number of items a line can fit.
Point 3 in first paragraph already mentions `Each product P is a set of Items`. Not sure why is it still unclear.

Comment: Because the first sentence refers to "capacity", without explaining what that refers to. Reading further it's not clear if it refers to numbers of products or items. Only the latter makes sense, however. You could avoid all that by initially referring to items, then when you  refer to assembly lines you can be clear that its capacity is the maximum number of items the line can process. Further, when you speak of products you can say that each product is comprised of a given subset of items.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was checking the solution you posted. I noticed it's already deleted now. 

In your solution you suggested to use ILP and formulate the problem as linear equations satisfying constraints. 

I wanted to ask how you would avoid the duplicate counting of items on assembly line ? Example: P1 and P2 are placed on Line L1 and lets assume they share 2 common items, then I don't want to count items twice while checking for capacity. 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I amended my answer to give an example of finding an optimal solution rather than one that is just feasible.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be formulated as an integer, linear program, and then solved with any commercial or public-domain ILP solver.

**Givens**

We are given the following:

- A : the number of assembly lines, indexed by a
- P : the number of products, indexed by p
- I : the number of items, indexed by i
- C<sub>a</sub> : the maximum number of items that can be processed by assembly line a
- S<sub>i</sub> : the set of products that use item i

The formulation of the ILP model is as follows.

**Variables**

We define the following variables.

x<sub>pa</sub> equals 1 if product p is assigned to assembly line a, else 0, 1 ≤ p ≤ P, 1 ≤ a ≤ A

y<sub>ai</sub> equals 1 if item i is processed on assembly line a, else 0, 1 ≤ a ≤ A, 1 ≤ i ≤ I

**Constraints**

The constraints are as follows:

*Each product must be produced*

∑<sub>a</sub>x<sub>pa</sub> = 1, 1 ≤ p ≤ P

*Prevent production of a product on a given assembly line if it contains an item that is not permitted on that line*

x<sub>pa</sub> ≤ y<sub>ai</sub> for each i in S<sub>i</sub>, 1 ≤ a ≤ A, 1 ≤ i ≤ I

*The capacity of each assembly line cannot be exceeded*

∑<sub>i</sub>y<sub>ai</sub> ≤ C<sub>a</sub>, for a = 1,...,A

**Objective function**

There is no objective function to be maximized or minimized as only a feasible solution is required. If the solver does require an objective function, something artificial could be used, such as

min 0x<sub>11</sub>

---

**Optimizing**

Suppose now we wish to maximize or minimize some function, not just identify a feasible solution.

As an example, suppose it costs c<sub>a</sub> to operate assembly line a and we now want to determine which assembly lines to open to minimize cost. We could do that as follows.

We define the following additional variables.

z<sub>a</sub> equals 1 if assembly line is to operate, else 0, 1 ≤ a ≤ A

The revised formulation follows.

min ∑<sub>a</sub>c<sub>a</sub>z<sub>a</sub>

subject to:

∑<sub>a</sub>x<sub>pa</sub> = 1, 1 ≤ p ≤ P

x<sub>pa</sub> ≤ y<sub>ai</sub> for each i in S<sub>i</sub>, 1 ≤ a ≤ A, 1 ≤ i ≤ I

∑<sub>i</sub>y<sub>ai</sub> - C<sub>a</sub>z<sub>a</sub> ≤ 0, for a = 1,...,A

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem. I used Python pulp library to solve this.

```
We need to define following binary variables:
x[i, j] = true, if product i is placed on line j
y[j, k] = true, if item k is placed on line j

Constraints: 
1. Σ y[j, k] <= Cj, where Cj is the capacity of the line j
2. Σ x[i, j] = 1, a product can be assigned to only one line.
3. y[j, k] >= x[i, j], set y[j, k] = true for line j if product x[i, j] = true for line j.
```

Code:

```
    from pulp import *
    
    def solve_assembly_line_assignment(capacities, products):
        M = len(products)
        N = len(capacities)
        all_items = set()
        for prod in products:
            all_items = all_items.union(prod)
        K = len(all_items)
    
        # Create a binary variable x[i][j] representing whether product i is assigned to assembly line j
        x = LpVariable.dicts("Product", [(i, j) for i in range(1, M + 1) for j in range(1, N + 1)], 0, 1, LpBinary)
    
        # Create a binary variable y[i][k] representing whether item k is used on assembly line j
        y = LpVariable.dicts("Item", [(j, k) for j in range(1, N + 1) for k in range(1, K + 1)], 0, 1, LpBinary)
    
        # Create the LP problem
        prob = LpProblem("Assembly_Line_Assignment", LpMaximize)
    
        # Objective function: maximize the total assignment value
        # This function is not necessary, as total sum of all products on all lines = total sum of all products in this case.
        prob += lpSum(x[i, j] for i in range(1, M + 1) for j in range(1, N + 1)), "Total_Assignment_Value"
    
        # Constraints: each product is assigned to exactly one assembly line
        for i in range(1, M + 1):
            prob += lpSum(x[i, j] for j in range(1, N + 1)) == 1, f"Product_Assignment_{i}"
    
        # Constraints: assembly line capacity
        for j in range(1, N + 1):
            prob += lpSum(y[j, k] for k in range(1, K + 1)) <= capacities[j - 1], f"Assembly_Line_Capacity_{j}"
    
        # Constraints: link y and x variables
        for i in range(1, M + 1):
            for j in range(1, N + 1):
                for k in range(1, K + 1):
                    # This constraint ensures that when x[i, j] assumes value 1 then it's item also does so.
                    # This helps in checking previous constraint of capacity without double counting.
                    if k in products[i-1]:
                        prob += y[j, k] >= x[i, j], f"Link_{i}_{k}_{j}"
    
        prob.writeLP("assembly_line_model.lp")
    
        # Solve the problem
        prob.solve()
    
        # Print the results
        print(f"Products: {products}")
        print(f"Lines: {capacities}")
        print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
        print("Optimal Assignment:")
        for i in range(1, M + 1):
            for j in range(1, N + 1):
                if value(x[i, j]) == 1:
                    print(f"Product {i} is assigned to Assembly Line {j}")
```

Example usage:

```
capacities = [3, 4, 4]  # Capacities of assembly lines
products = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 5}]  # Products as sets of items
solve_assembly_line_assignment(capacities, products)
```

Result:

```
Optimal Assignment:
Product 1 is assigned to Assembly Line 3
Product 2 is assigned to Assembly Line 3
Product 3 is assigned to Assembly Line 1
Product 4 is assigned to Assembly Line 2
Product 5 is assigned to Assembly Line 2
```

Comment: Very good! I see we came to the same formulation. (Readers: due an initial misunderstanding of the question I posted a different formulation of the model than what my current answer shows. Then havish posted his solution while I was working on my revision, so we came upon the same formulation independently.) Kudos to hamish for implementing it as well! Incidentally, math programming questions should be posted at Stack Exchange's [OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/) community, though you may not have thought about a math programming formulation when you posted the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the hints you shared earlier !
However, I notice now that on a real world data set - 24 Lines, 100 Products & 500 Items, my program takes a long time to solve. approx 20 mins! Now I need to figure out how do I reduce the running time. I will do more research on this topic.

Comment: What solver are you using? If you are a student you may be able to use CPLEX and GUROBI for free. Is this an actual application?

Comment: CBC - this one's the default for pulp. This is for an actual application at work.

Comment: I'm curious as to why 20 minutes is a problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland 
So, the use case that I have is that every week when production starts in the warehouse I get a new dataset of Assembly Line, products and items. The end users want to run this matching algorithm and expects the result to be returned as quickly as possible. I am wondering how I can speed it up, meanwhile I am also trying to get access to a commercial solver.

Comment: Please keep me posted. It sounds like an interesting application. Do you have any interest to optimize rather than finding a feasible solution? Don't forget to make an estimation of how much money you've saved the company and have that with you during your next performance review, especially when you talk salary and promotion.

Comment: Quick update, I was able to bring down the execution time significantly to <= 1 min for my data set. 
To achieve this, I used a free CP-SAT solver provided by OR-tools https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model

Comment: havish, good on you. I'll have a look at that solver. You're work to make it run faster suggests you are frequently re-optimizing with updated data. Correct?