# Grouping Algorithm for Temperature Range [Revised]

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, grouping

Note that this is a more detailed version of a previous, closed question.

I have a scenario where I have `N` items (`N` is a large number), and each item has a minimum allowable temperature (`min_temp`) and a maximum allowable temperature (`max_temp`).

I need to find a setpoint temperature that maximizes the number of items where that setpoint is between their `min_temp` and `max_temp` values. Ideally, it finds the value that also gives the greatest buffer between the setpoint and the closest min/max value of the compatible items (i.e. the safest setpoint in case of fluctuations).

A brute-force approach would be to loop through possible temperatures at a certain step size, such as:

```
float best_temp;
size_t best_num_items = 0;
for(float t = -60; t < 100; t += 0.1) {
    size_t num_items = 0;
    for(auto item: items) {
        if(t >= item.min_temp && t <= item.max_temp) {
            num_items++;
        }
    }
    if(num_items > best_num_items) {
        best_num_items = num_items;
        best_temp      = t;
    }
}
```

This would give me the best setpoint, but (a) it's obviously wildly inefficient, (b) it doesn't account for finding the value with the greatest buffer as detailed above, and (c) it negates all possible values that may be between step sizes.

Is there a non-brute-force approach that I should consider for this?

Comment: Everything except the "greatest buffer" part (which is ill-posed until you specify whether you're willing to lose one item to give another a better buffer) is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14780324/8586227).

Comment: `for(float t = -60; t < 100; t += 0.1)` --Off topic, but this loop has issues.  How many times will this loop iterate?  You are adding `0.1` to a float, and this may lead to the loop not executing the number of times you expect, due to floating point issues and exact calculations.  If you know you need to iterate `n` times, then the `for` loop should use integer loop variables, not floating point.  Maybe `for (int n = -600; n < 1000; ++n) { float x = n / 10.0; // then use x }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of choosing a set point temperature between given minimum and maximum values that maximizes the number of items for which the chosen set point falls between each item's minimum and maximum value can be modelled as an integer linear programming problem and solved with an ILP software package.

The formulation of the model follows.

**Data**

- SP<sub>l</sub> : minimum set point temperature
- SP<sub>h</sub> : maximum set point temperature
- X<sub>il</sub> : minimum temperature for item i
- X<sub>ih</sub> : maximum temperature for item i

**Variables**

- sp : a continuous variable equal to the set point
- x<sub>i</sub> : = 1 if item i is selected as part of the group; else = 0

**Mixed integer program**

max Σ<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub>

subject to:

sp + (SP<sub>h</sub>-X<sub>ih</sub>)x<sub>i</sub> ≤ SP<sub>h</sub>    for all i

-sp + (SP<sub>l</sub>+X<sub>il</sub>)x<sub>i</sub> ≤ SP<sub>l</sub>    for all i

sp ≤ SP<sub>h</sub>

-sp ≤ -SP<sub>l</sub>

---

Note that the first two groups of constraints are derived from the following, respectively.

sp ≤ X<sub>ih</sub>x<sub>i</sub> + SP<sub>h</sub>(1-x<sub>i</sub>)

which reduces to:

sp ≤ X<sub>ih</sub>    if x<sub>i</sub> = 1

sp ≤ SP<sub>h</sub>    if x<sub>i</sub> = 0

Similarly,

sp ≥ X<sub>il</sub>x<sub>i</sub> - SP<sub>l</sub>(1-x<sub>i</sub>)

which reduces to:

sp ≥ X<sub>il</sub>    if x<sub>i</sub> = 1

sp ≥ SP<sub>l</sub>    if x<sub>i</sub> = 0

---

See @havish's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78132958/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-assigning-products-to-assembly-lines/78133760#78133760) for an example of using an ILP solver with Python.

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware of any ILP packages that would be compatible with C11 (for an embedded device)?

Comment: I really don't know, but I've heard that [coin-or/Cbc](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc), which is written in C++, is possibly the best public domain ILP solver.  I'd be grateful if you'd keep me (and others) posted on how your project is progressing. Incidentally, rather than the current objective above you could attach a weight to each variable if that would be helpful.